# NSIS Error Launching Installer - Unicode characters in Windows Username

Tags: installation, unicode, nsis

When downloading and running an EXE installer on my new laptop I get the NSIS Error Launching Installer. When the same installation is downloaded on a different computer and transferred via USB drive, it works fine. What is causing the NSIS error?

Answer (score 0):

The root of the issue was the Unicode characters in my local windows account username, so after creating a new account and removing the old one everything worked fine.